# Python SciPy convolve vs fftconvolve

Tags: python, scipy, fft, convolution

I know generally speaking `FFT and multiplication` is usually faster than direct `convolve` operation, when the array is relatively large. However, I'm convolving a very long signal (say 10 million points) with a very short response (say 1 thousand points). In this case the `fftconvolve` doesn't seem to make much sense, since it forces a FFT of the second array to the same size of the first array. Is it faster to just do direct convolve in this case?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just time both approaches, eg with `timeit`?

Comment: I didn't know this function. I'll try. I also would like to know underlying theory though.

Comment: Note: As of v0.19, convolve automatically chooses fftconvolve or the direct method based on an estimation of which is faster.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the comparison I did here:

http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ApplyFIRFilter.html

Your case might be near the transition between using a plain convolution and using the FFT-based convolution, so your best bet (as suggested by @Dougal in a comment) is to time it yourself.

(Note that I didn't do overlap-add or overlap-save in that comparison.)

Comment: the link seems to not pointing to what you meant (even though I could find it anyway in the page)

Comment: @luca Thanks.  That page was originally on the old scipy wiki, which is gone now.  I've updated the link.

Answer (score 5):

thank you for your help. Now I did the test myself, I did convolution with 2 arrays, size of 2^20 and 2^4, and this is the result:

```
numpy.convolve: 110 ms
scipy.signal.convolve: 1.0 s
scipy.signal.fftconvolve: 2.5 s
```

So we have a winner, numpy convolve is is much faster than the others. I still don't know why though.

---

Now I tried 2 longer arrays, size of 2^22 and 2^10. The result is:

```
numpy.convolve: 6.7 s
scipy.signal.convolve: 221 s
scipy.signal.fftconvolve: MemoryError
```

The difference just gets bigger.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Maybe [related](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8154).

Answer (score 4):

FFT fast convolution via the overlap-add or overlap save algorithms can be done in limited memory by using an FFT that is only a small multiple (such as 2X) larger than the impulse response.  It breaks the long FFT up into properly overlapped shorter but zero-padded FFTs.

Even with the overlap overhead, O(NlogN) will beat M*N in efficiency for large enough N and M.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you mean even with the `fftconvolve` function, it will automatically break down long FFT into short FFTs and I do not need to worry about it?

Comment: @LWZ: scipy's fftconvolve does not do that, no.  hotpaw, do you have a reference/implementation for that method?