# How to np.convolve over two 2d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to carry out np.convolve for two 2d arrays in a vectorized manner. Here is the thing:

The function [`np.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html?highlight=convolve#numpy.convolve) takes two 1d arrays, `a` and `v`, and computes the convolution. The result reads:

```
output[n] = \sum_m a[m] v[n - m] .
```

What I want to do is, for 2d arrays `a` and `v`, to repeat "convolution along axis=0" over axis=1. That is,

```
output[n][k] = \sum_m a[m][k] v[n - m][k] .
```

Though this is attained by a for statement with respect to the axis=1, I'm keen on finding a way to "vectorize" this to improve performance.

I looked up for a while but no clue. I'm glad if someone could find a way out. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of your arrays it may be quicker to do a multiplication of the fft arrays, which is mathematically equivalent to the convolution operation. Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32029836/10475762), it is quicker, however it appears limited when you get to **exceptionally** long sequences, as proven [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018526/python-scipy-convolve-vs-fftconvolve). An example of what this could look like:

```
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
output = fftconvolve(a, v, mode='same') #mode='full', too
```

If they help you don't forget to give them an upvote, too :).